# How to fix "Not inside a Git work tree" with SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

i started a localhost SonarQube server, then i added sonarscanner for maven plugin to my pom.xml but when i start Analyzing following this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/ i get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project teamup: Not inside a Git work tree: C:\Users\alexc\OneDrive\Desktop\teamup -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project teamup: Not inside a Git work tree: C:\Users\alexc\OneDrive\Desktop\teamup
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Not inside a Git work tree: C:\Users\alexc\OneDrive\Desktop\teamup
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:67)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
> Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Not inside a Git work tree: C:\Users\alexc\OneDrive\Desktop\teamup

SonarQube 8.4.1
SonarScanner for Maven 3.7
JDK 1.11

This only happens with this project.
It's a Spring Boot project.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this problem, if you set the property `sonar.projectBaseDir`:

```sh
sonar.projectBaseDir="repository-path"
```

I found this solution in a [Sonarqube community question](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-scanner-fails-with-not-inside-a-git-worktree-error/26914).

**EDIT**:

And please make sure that you use a git project with a `.git` folder.

Comment: i created a file called sonar-project of properties type and i wrote in: `sonar.projectBaseDir="C:\Users\alexc\eclipse-workspaceweb\teamup"` and i put it in the main folder where there is the pom.xml, but i got the same problem.

Comment: Okay then I have only one suggestion: Have you tried the [official example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-maven)? Does it work for you?

Comment: no it doesn't, i tried creating a sample project and it works fine, it can analyze, i don't understand what could be.

Comment: And in your folder there is also a `.git` folder? Maybe you can publish your project and somebody can try it out?

Comment: i just created a new repository with Git GUI and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

to disable scm, add `-Dsonar.scm.disabled=true` to command

Comment: That is not a good solution if you want everything (including SCM) to work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sonar scanner is not able to find the repository your source code cloned in. Add below properties

```
sonar.projectBaseDir="<Path_to_project_where_project_is_cloned>"
sonar.sources=.
sonar.scm.provider=git
```